# Get Android AudioRecord startRecording time delay

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiorecord

I am using the `AudioRecord` class from https://github.com/nonameentername/soundtouch-android/blob/master/src/org/tecunhuman/ExtAudioRecorder.java but with it being slightly modified.

In the `start()` method, I start recording with the `AudioRecord` class.  I also start a `MediaPlayer` to play a instrumental.  To get the vocals and the instrumental to mix at the right positions on the server, I send the instrumental delay to pad the instrumental at the beginning with silence (beatDelayInSeconds - `MediaPlayer` delay from when start is called to it actually being played since there is latency when starting media player).

My logic must be wrong because the timing on the playback of the vocals and the instrumental is off on the device. Some times the recording will be too fast, sometimes it will be too slow in comparison to when the instrumental is playing. Any suggestions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For better explanation:

Voice Recording Started

|----------------------------------------|

Beat/Instrumental Starts playing afterwards

[X]|-----------------------------------------------|

I am trying to find X so I can send that to startPlayback() method as beatDelayInSeconds and to the server.  X is the time between when the voice starts recording until the beat actually starts playing. Currently in my startPlayback() method, plays both beat and vocals back, they are not in sync like it was recorded.  Hope this makes sense.

Note: I had to put the delay handler in there for some Jelly Bean devices because the `AudioRecord` listener was not being called.

```
public void start()
{
    if (state == State.READY)
    {
        if (rUncompressed)
        {
            payloadSize = 0;
            RecordReadDelayInSeconds = 0;
            RecordDelayInSeconds = 0;

            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            try {

                mPlayer.setDataSource(mp3Path);

                mPlayer.prepare();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
              catch (SecurityException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
              catch (IllegalStateException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
              catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}

            final long recordstarted = System.nanoTime() + 1500000000; //handler delay

            audioRecorder.startRecording();

            //Fix for recording issue with Samsung s3 Sprint phones.Doing a delayed first read
              new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {                    
                   @Override
                    public void run() {

                       long recordstopped = System.nanoTime();

                        long recordDelay = recordstopped - recordstarted;

                        double RecordDelayInSeconds = recordDelay / 1000000.0;

                        Log.i("StartRecording() Delay in seconds",
                                String.valueOf(RecordDelayInSeconds));

                        long recordreadstarted = System.nanoTime();

                        int bytesReceived = audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        Log.d(TAG,"Delayed first read: bytes recieved "+ bytesReceived);

                        long recordreadstopped = System.nanoTime();

                        long recordreadDelay = recordreadstopped - recordreadstarted;

                        RecordReadDelayInSeconds = recordreadDelay / 1000000.0;

                        Log.i("Record read() Delay in seconds",
                                String.valueOf(RecordReadDelayInSeconds));

                        long mediastarted = System.nanoTime();

                        mPlayer.start();

                        long mediastopped = System.nanoTime();

                        long beatDelay = mediastopped - mediastarted;

                        beatDelayInSeconds = 0;

                        beatDelayInSeconds = (beatDelay) / 1000000000.0;

                        Log.i("Beat Delay in seconds",
                                String.valueOf(beatDelayInSeconds));

                    }
                }, 1500);
}
```

This is the playback code that the user listens to before sending info to server.  It first starts the playback of the wav the user just recorded and then plays the instrumental according to the beatDelayInSeconds variable from the other method.

```
private void startPlayback() {

    wavPlayer.start();
    RefreshHandler mp3PlaybackHandler = new RefreshHandler();
            mp3PlaybackHandler.sleep((long) (beatDelayInSeconds * 1000));

}

class RefreshHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mp3Player.start();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "Beat delayed for " + delayMillis + " milliseconds");
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
};
```

Comment: @nawlrus.. In your question, you have quoted " To get these to sync at the server". I understand that you are trying to record and simultaneously playback a content. I couldn't understand the context of the reproduced comment. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry Ganesh.  I have edited and added more info.  I send the beatDelayInseconds and the a recordDelay which is equal to RecordReadDelayInSeconds + RecordDelayInSeconds.  The server takes care of the media processing from there but I dont think I am getting the correct delays there for processing and for playback after doing the recording.

Comment: @nawlrus.. So if I understand correctly, you are trying to record some data, stream it to a server, receive the same back from the server and play it back on the same device. Is this understanding correct? If this is true, if recording session is ON during playback, won't you encounter an in-loop echo or background echo? Is this acceptable? Another point. Even if a recorder has a start-up latency, once it starts streaming out data, it has to adhere to some bitrate regulations, so even if your mediaplayer starts late, it shouldn't ideally have an underflow. Isn't this the case?

Comment: @Ganesh.  I have the user record their vocals and then at that time they can play it back on the device (without sending to the server, just playing the vocals and beat back; See the startPlayback method) This is where I hear that the timing is off.  If the users likes the recording, at that point I send the beatDelayInSeconds to the server where it mixes both the vocals and instrumentals together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand "**the timing is always off**"? what does it mean?

I am not so clear about your question and your description, but Is it true: You want to postpone the execution of a code block after some period of time?

If it's the case, you must consider whether your **`new Handler().postDelayed(..)`** is called inside another UI thread or not. Try this if it's an activity's process:

```
your_activity_instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
               //delay with thread
               try{
                   Thread.sleep(1500);
               }catch(.....)
               {..}

               //your work load here
            }
});
```

NOTE:

- Handler.postDelayed() does NOT create a separated thread for your code block, but only append a new message (related to your Runnable instance) with timer sticker into current thread's message queue.
- activity.runOnUiThread() do the similar thing but the **`Runnable.run()`** has to wait until the system comes back to activity UI thread then be excuted. This's helpful when you want to do some activity's job in its child thread.

**Update for modified question:**

I may understand your intention: trying to execute **`wavPlayer.start()`** and **`mp3Player.start()`** at the same time; but your current solution is not nice or even it is impossible:

- In the same thread which you are using handlers, you will hardly sync the 2 functions (as I mention, handler.run() doesn't spawn separated thread).
- you can not pin down the exact time stamp of **`hanler.run()`** because the system controls when the message is appended to the queue, the post delayed is a relative value.

My suggested solution:

- You spawn a separated thread for each player.
- Before each thread start(), you mark the time stamp (may use millisecs, not such of accuracy to use nano)
- In the second thread which is called later, you also pass to it the DELTA of time stamps (diff between markers). Then use **`Thread.Sleep()`** or **`Handler.postDelayed()`** for your adjustment of sync.

Comment: Edited the question.  I need the vocals and the instrumental to playback on the device the same way they recorded it.  Currently the playback is out of sync.  The vocals would either be delayed or too fast in comparison with the instrumental.